# Is it possible that Lost mode for my phone was deactivated by a thief?

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

Why my iPhone cannot detect the location? I enable the lost mode and its confirmed by email but the device did not show any location. But when I first set my lost mode they asked me a pass code, but now if I turn on my lost mode the phone never ask me a pass code. It only appears on the screen that it is done. What is the problem with that? It's possible that my lost mode and Apple ID are hacked by the thief or they deactivated it.

Comment: I am unclear on what you are asking. Are you stating that somebody stole your phone? Are you asking if they could have disabled Find My iPhone on the phone itself?

Comment: To check your AppleID change the password.

Comment: I've lost my iphone ... i turn on the lost mode the first time i use lost mode and its done with passcode but the lost mode has been disable then i try to on again my lost mode there is no passcode provide just only done ...

Comment: I've lost my iphone ...5 days ago 1st time i turn my lost mode theres a 4 digit security code the email confirm me that the lost has been enable and he give the latest location where is my phone and then the other day the lost mode have been disable so i turn on again my lost mode no pass code needed  but it is only done then the email confirm me again lost mode is enable but there is no location to be shown after that my lost mode is disable again....

Comment: i use window to activate the lost mode

Comment: icloud activation lock can be by pass and the lost mode passcode can also be bypass

Answer (score 1):

They could just have to phone turned off. Although if your phone is logged into itunes, it's POSSIBLE (with forensic software or more knowledge than most iphone thieves) to get your itunes user and password and then of course they could turn it off. However, I think it is an easy thing to determine if someone else is logging in with your credentials, so I'd be willing to bet that they just have the phone turned off.